# @gorhom/bottom-sheet not rendering the text of the clicked button

Tags: react-native, expo, bottom-sheet

I am trying to create a user prompt UI where users can click on the button and the bottom sheet pops up but the issue I have is the text doesn't change according to the originally declared.

[[image: Code Image]

[image]

Here is the code snippet: https://gist.github.com/olasubomi-o/f2b549b855a3b690a86521e44c9df4bf

Comment: you need to add source code not just image.

Comment: Just added a code snippet

Comment: from the gif you added it doesnt seem like you are typing anything. what happens when you type and click save? also whats the unhandled promise rejection warning ?

Comment: The problem is not the input text but the heading text